# Modify CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX for subdirs

Tags: cmake, installation

I have a project which should be installed at `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` (supplied by user).

I include a sub-project with `add_subdirectory(subproject)`.  This subproject installs content to `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}`, but I'd rather install it to `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/subproject`.  How can I do that without touching the subproject?

I've tried this: But it had no effect:

```
set( _INSTALL_PREFIX_BACKUP ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
set( CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/subproject)
add_subdirectory(subproject)
set( CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${_INSTALL_PREFIX_BACKUP})
```

I've also tried this:

```
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add( subproject
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/subproject
    CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/subproject"
    INSTALL_DIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/subproject"
)
```

Comment: Not sure about Windows, but on Linux installing both main and subproject into the **same directory** (using same *CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX*) is OK. Moreover, installing the subproject into subdirectory is somehow unusual for the user. You may think about *CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX* as not per-project directory, but **per-environment** one. One environment may contain many projects installed, which interfer with each other. Again, this is about Linux. As for your attempts, using `ExternalProject` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with.  In the subproject:

```
if (SUBPROJECT_INSTALL_PREFIX)
  set(_SUBPROJECT_INSTALL_PREFIX ${SUBPROJECT_INSTALL_PREFIX}/ )
else()
  set(_SUBPROJECT_INSTALL_PREFIX . )
endif()

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
        RUNTIME DESTINATION ${_SUBPROJECT_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${_SUBPROJECT_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/static
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${_SUBPROJECT_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib)
```

In the super-project, I then use:

```
set(SUBPROJECT_INSTALL_PREFIX "path/to/subproject" CACHE STRING "Path in project")
add_subdirectory(subproject)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's all about the `install()` function.

In your subproject's `CMakeLists.txt` you need the following line:

```
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} LIBRARY DESTINATION subproject)
```

Depending on your usecase you can adjust `LIBRARY` to `RUNTIME`.
`subproject` here is the path. It's relative to `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}`.

Have the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/install.html) here for reference.

Comment: The trick here is that I'd like my subproject to be agnostic to the superproject.  The subproject is being used in multiple super-projects and will be installed in different locations in each super-project.  I suppose my best bet is to add a string option to the cache of the sub-project to set the installation prefix.